# PHP Class: Array deinitialized after constructor?

Tags: php, arrays, class, constructor, initialization

Im making a class in php, but Im having some problems with one of the class variables. I declare a private variable, then in the constructor set it. However, later in the class I have a method that uses that variable. The variable in this case is an array. However, the method says the array is blank, but when I check it in the constructor, it all works out fine. So really the question is, why does my array clear, or seem to clear, after the constructor?

```
<?php
class Module extends RestModule {
    private $game;
    private $gamearray;

    public function __construct() {
        require_once (LIB_DIR."arrays/gamearray.php");
        $this->gamearray = $gamesarray;
        $this->game = new Game();
        $this->logger = Logger::getLogger(__CLASS__);
        $this->registerMethod('add', array(Rest::AUTH_PUBLIC, Rest::AUTH_USER, Rest::AUTH_ADMIN), true);
        $this->registerMethod('formSelect', array(Rest::AUTH_PUBLIC, Rest::AUTH_USER, Rest::AUTH_ADMIN), false);
    }

    public function add(){
        $game = Utility::post('game');        
    }

    public function formSelect(){
        $gamename = Utility::get('game');
        $this->$gamearray[$gamename];
    }
}
```

The array is pulled in from another file because the array contains a lot of text. Didn't want to mash up this file with a huge array declared in the constructor. The scrolling would be tremendous. Any explanation would be nice, I like to understand my problems, not just fix em'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
public function formSelect(){
    $gamename = Utility::get('game');
    $this->gamearray[$gamename]; // Remove the $ before gamearray
}
```

Moreover, in your case, `include` is better than `require_once`.

If you want to go deeper, you could rewrite `$gamearray` assignment like this:

```
// Module.php 
$this->gamearray = include LIB_DIR.'arrays/gamearray.php';

// gamearray.php
return array(
    // Your data here
);
```

Comment: Should have gone to bed and relooked at it so I would feel less stupid, oh well thanks a lot! And I learned the include thing too, so thanks a lot!!!